# div com base em raio - border-radius ou outro metodo?

Tags: html, css

Preciso criar uma div com a base em raio igual da imagem em anexo.
Porem não estou conseguindo achar o valor exato no border-radius para deixar igual a imagem, existe alguma outra forma de fazer isso? Lembrando que preciso deixar responsivo.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou fazendo uns teste no fiddle com border-radius mas ta difícil deixar igual.
https://fiddle.jshell.net/163d0bs5/1/

Obs.: A seta não faz parte da dúvida.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que você pode aumentar a largura da `div`, para que o raio de borda fique mais suave, mas para que não estrague o layout, utilizar `overflow: hidden` na div mãe.

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #e4f0f6;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.test {
  width: 110%;
  margin: 0 -5%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 40px 0;
  border-radius: 0 0 500% 500%;
}

.arrow {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  border-top: 20px solid white;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="test">
    <h1>Teste com borda!</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="arrow"></div>
</div>
```

É isso que precisa?

Comment: Ola, primeiramente muito obrigado, é mais ou menos isso, o problema que não estou conseguindo dixar igual a image, e tb preciso que seja responsivo.

Seria muito primitivo da minha parte usar a imagem como bg? ou como imagem mesmo posicionando na base da div?  vlw

Comment: O que seria "fixar igual a imagem"? Dá para dizer que o meu exemplo é responsivo, variando levemente a curvatura para diferentes tamanhos de tela, mas dependendo do caso, isso pouca diferença faz.

Comment: Posicionaria o background-image na parte de baixo da div, ou usava uma img com position absolute e bottom 0, vou fazer mais teste aqui com imagem e com o border-radius mesmo.

Comment: Vou usar seu metodo, acho q consegui chegar em uma condição satisfatória. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Uma outra forma de fazer é usando a propriedade [`radial-gradient()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/radial-gradient) do `background`. Veja:

```css
.container{
  width:100%;
  background-color:#e4f0f6;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  height:100vh;
}
.test{
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
  padding:40px 0;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 50% 50% / 0 0 25% 25%;
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center,#fff 15%,#fff 0%,#fff 57%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="test">
    <h1>Teste com borda!</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Mas no meu caso é somente a base que tem raio, to tentando ir mudando o valor do border-radius mas ta difícil chegar na condição da imagem. Mas  vou tentar mais , obrigado.